# Can you load a .docx file in a JavaFX interface using Scene Builder?

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, docx

I'm trying to build a java application using JavaFX which has a list of objects displayed in a table and each object has a word document associated with it. Also the table has a double click event for each line which loads up the word document and displays it in another section. The two sections are placed inside a Split Pane. Is it possible to load a word document using JavaFX? If not, a pdf file should be fine as well, but I can't find any good tutorials for Java 8.

Comment: You will need to use a library that can parse a word document or pdf and exposes either a graphics context, renders the content (to image etc) that you can place into your UI, or a library that lets you grab the contents of the document/pdf in a format that you can use (text, image, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some candidates to look at:

https://poi.apache.org/ for MS docs in general

https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/PDFViewFX for PDF viewing

And upgrade to a more recent version of Java. 16 is the current version - not 8.